# How to set text color in code to a android widget?

Tags: android, colors, android-widget, widget

I have an android widget that updates and chose a random int from 4 numbers, if the number equals 1 i want it to set the text color to a specific color i tried:

```
if (colornumb == 1)
        {
        view.setTextColor(R.id.text1, Color.rgb(200, 0, 0));
        }
```

and it don't work i get white not red.
I will appreciate a good answer, Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem thanks for your answers.(It did not update because i had a configure activity. It just copy/paste the color changer code in the configure activity and updated the views from there.)

Comment: Is it a list item or a normal TextView?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It did not update because i had a configure activity. It just copy/paste the color changer code in the configure activity and updated the views from there.

Answer (score 1):

just use this one

```
view.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    view.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    view.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
```

and shave color value in `res/values/colors.xml`

```
colors.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources> 

     <color name="white">#fff</color>
     <color name="red">#DF1111</color>
     <color name="green">#63DF11</color>

  </resources>
```

in Widget try this one

```
Widget.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

and this

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.message, "setBackgroundColor" android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
if (colornumb == 1)
        {
        //view.setTextColor(R.id.text1, Color.RED);
        view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
        }
```

Comment: The same result i get white.

Comment: it don't work, It sure work for normal android apps but not for widgets

Comment: @user2635745 then more code needed widget are also created from views

Comment: @user2635745 show more code your xml may be some thing you are missing

Comment: color xml or layout ?

Comment: Neither xml nor layout its Class

Comment: sorry by layout i meant class, i don't have any other code that have an importance in this, this code will work if i have a random color and use `if (colornumb == 1)
        {
        view.setTextColor(R.id.text1, randomColor);
        }`